# Change content depending where scrollbar is currently at?

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is there a way to change for instance a the color of a link depending how far you have scrolled down? I'm guessing this would be accomplished with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and doesn't require jQuery. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scrollTop` property to see how far the page is scrolled down.

jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop

and `$("html").scroll(function(){...});` for the scroll event.

`$('a').css('color', 'blue')` to change color.